# Impact of not having social network account during a job change.

Tags: software-industry, career-development, hiring-process, job-change, networking

I am a 22 year old software developer and I do not have a Facebook, Twitter or LinkedIn account and I have never felt the need of having one, but with the advancement of people wanting to know you by your social identity, I  feel it might affect me during the job interview.

What issue I could use the workplace help with: **Is it important during the HR round to portray an image of being very friendly and nice?**

Comment: Friendly and nice !== having social media accounts.

Comment: The title of your post is out of sync with your question. Are you asking about social media, or are you asking about the importance of being very friendly and nice? Edit your post accordingly.

Comment: If you're a developer, it's more important to portray an image of being a skilled developer than it is to come off as friendly and nice.  You don't need Facebook, LinkedIn, or Twitter.  Github, on the other hand, would be a very good idea.

Comment: @aroth:  GitHub isn't really essential, either.  Mine would be empty if I had one because very little of what I've worked on in my career are things the people who hired me would want released to the public.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about navigating the workplace

Comment: war_Hero, I've put this question on hold so you can clarify which question you're asking.  I think the one in bold in your question is too subjective/opinion-based, but a question about the absence of social-media connections while job-hunting could fit.

Comment: What having linked in is especially useful for, is if you attended conferences and other networking events, you meet people, and get along with them, it's a good way of keeping in touch with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not nice. I am not friendly. I am not cute. And I am not cuddly. I am here at an interview because they want me to show that I understand the job, I can do the job and I work well with the team. Period. And they want me to show all of that before they lay some real money on me in the form of salary and benefits. Everything else is either fluff or nonsense.

Yes, if the two of us are nearly equally qualified but you are the more affable, you'll probably get the nod. But you got the nod because you met the requirements of the job. Otherwise, I am the one who gets the key card access to the office.

Comment: Two words - cultural fit. Call it "fluff or nonsense", but it's still something a lot of employers look for. And one can argue that lack of friendliness and niceness can interfere with the ability to work with others.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it important during the HR round to portray an image of being very
>   friendly and nice?

**No.**

When all the people who meet you during the interview process get together to discuss their impressions, the HR vote isn't nearly as important as the hiring manager's vote.  HR may point out red flags ("he complained about all his previous employers) but that's about it.

Having or not having social media accounts isn't going to matter to HR.

---

Your implied question

"**What's the value of social media accounts and should I have them?**"

Networking was important 30 years ago, it's important now, and it'll be important 30 years from now.  If you choose to use social media tools to stay in touch with people you meet during your career, there may come a day when you're in a position to help someone **or get help**.

A lot of people get jobs and promotions this way.

You don't have to do it, but if you do you'll have an advantage over those who don't.

Stay in touch with people and have lunch with them occasionally.